# Julia analog for Matlab mrdivide

Tags: matlab, julia

I wonder if there's a standard function in Julia for Matlab's [mrdivide](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)? `x = B/A` which would solve the system of linear equations `x*A = B` for `x`. As far as I have seen, the standard [linalg](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/) package does not have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just works. To solve `x * A = B` for `x`: (`mrdivide`)

```
B / A
```

To solve `A * x = B` for `x`: (`mldivide`)

```
A \ B
```

The `\` symbol means divide from the left, and the `/` symbol means divide from the right, as in MATLAB. You are correct that `/` is not documented for some reason. I do not know why.

Comment: I think the question was initially formulated in an ambiguous way: one have to read "function in Julia"

Comment: @ArtenOboturov `/` is a function in Julia! Try `/(1, 2)` or `map(/, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov I don't see what the problem is with this answer.  MATLAB's `mldivide` and `mrdivide` operators are exactly as seen in Julia.

Comment: @rayryeng I have not specified in the question that I was looking for a Julia function, so it was just a check. The question was fixed already.

Comment: `/` is documented: type `?/` at the REPL.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders It is not documented on [this page](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/), where one familiar with MATLAB may expect to find it. Its counterpart \ is documented.

Comment: Ah I see. You can suggest an improvement by using the pencil icon on the corresponding page in GitHub.

Comment: Also ``?\`` has a section ``\(A,B)`` which is missing from ``?/``